# Adding new images data to previously trained and saved tensorflow h5 model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have a pre-trained tensorflow h5 saved model to classify images.
here is the block of code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
model_version = "1"
model_name = "fresh-rotten-model"
model_path = os.path.join(model_name, model_version)
tf.saved_model.save(model, model_path)
model.save("fresh-rotten-model.h5")
```

I built a back-end that will upload new images every week using a schedule to a node server

Is there any way to add these images as a new data to train the model and build a new model without having to train the whole data set again ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just *add* data to a model file, a model file contains only weights, not the data used in it, so you'll have to have something (supposedly your backend server) do the training every time you want to update the model. You can kind of update the model by loading it and then doing more training epochs with it with the extended dataset, but other than that, there's not much you can do.

Comment: my question is how can i update the model with only the extended dataset

Comment: Basically, you can't. To properly train the model, you need all the present data. You can't train with just the extended dataset or the model will fit to just that part of the dataset. If you want to add more data like you said, you'll have to train on the entire dataset, what was there before, and the extended portion. There's just no way around it.